# Sublime Text 3 doesn't show separate files in tabs, how to switch between files?

Tags: sublime-text-3, user-interface, tabs, documents, sublime-text

If I open two files in Sublime Text 3 on macOS, the tab bar at the top only shows *one* item, i.e. just the last file I opened.

There is no visual feedback that the first file is also still open, and I can't seem to switch between them. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't switch back and forth (like it does in other software). The only way is clicking on the Window menu, that still shows the other file, and then manually selecting (clicking) it from there does work.

For example, if I first open `foo.txt` and then `bar.txt` I only see this:

[image: screenshot]

Note that if I just open `foo.txt` and then click <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to start a new file, it *does* show up as a separate tab next to the previously opened file:

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to configure Sublime Text 3 to show **all** open files in the tab bar at the top?

Comment: How do you open the files?

Comment: @idleberg Either by going to the particular file in Finder and doubleclicking it (Sublime Text 3 is my default editor), or selecting a file in Finder and pressing ⌘↓ or right-clicking the file and selecting Open, or Open With > Sublime Text 3, or from the terminal using `open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app foo.txt` (well, using an alias for the `open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app` part). The behavior is the same in all cases.

Comment: Is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765356/how-do-you-make-sublime-text-3-open-a-file-in-a-new-tab-instead-of-opening-it-in ?

Comment: Very good. You're welcome. That was quite easy :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found thanks to @AulisRonkainen in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50639000/3914111):

In preferences, add `"open_files_in_new_window": false`